# How to get result document in order of specified Ids in Ids query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to retrieve the documents of the index in order which the ids are specified in [Ids](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) query. Is there any way to get it?

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "query": { "ids": { "type": "_doc",  "values" : ["5", "15", "3", "2", "1", "9"] } } }'
```

I want the results in order if Ids specified above

`[ { _id: 5 }, { _id: 15 }, { _id: 3 }, { _id: 2 }, { _id: 1 }, { _id: 9 }]`

Comment: Give each one one constant descending score, but that would work in small set like this and will not scale

Comment: Thanks @sramalingam24. Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the suggestion provided by @sramalingam24 and it works as expected. Basically, tried to get the score of document more if it is in higher the order.

`size(list of Ids) - index(current document id)` will give me the required score.

The sample query is posted in gist [here](https://gist.github.com/RishikeshDarandale/445aeae51f82fee75b5a373df0be97d3).